# Websocket and WebRTC Gets Disconnected when in Background in iOS Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, background, webrtc

I have an app that broadcasts the screen recording but the connection for websocket and webrtc gets disconnected when I go to background (i go outside my app). The suggestions for adding background capability does not work.

Comment: have you used VoiP for background service?

Comment: yep did that one too, no success.

Comment: refer this link hope it works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987495/how-to-maintain-voip-socket-connection-in-background

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853812/prevent-websocket-connection-to-drop-when-entering-background-state-ios-swift