# waiting to a Websocket response in flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket

I am trying to establish connection with a server in flutter using web sockets. is there a way to listen to a response using Future and not Streams. my needed line of code is something like this :

```
 Future response = await ( expression to detect response from the server and return it);
```

does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getFunction() async {
 var url = 'your URL';   
 late String result;
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  result = response.body;
} else {
  print('Failed');
}
return result;
```

You can try this out,

Comment: is it necessary to use http.get()? i was hoping for something that uses websockets only

Comment: @Mufasa  you can check this link out. It uses websocket to get data and you can catch the error too if there is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502749/7972633

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful