# Parsing response from API call

Tags: flutter, api, rest

I am trying to parse an API response in a Future:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getReading() async {
  const uri = 'https://xxxxxxxxx';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri));

  if (response.statusCode == HTTP_OK) {
    var res = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    //var hc = res.data;
    return res;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Reading summary data.');
  }
}
```

The above code throws a run time error: `NoSuchMethodError.`

If I return directly the decoded `response.body`, it is something like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "data": {
        "hc": "148",
        "rc": "182"
    }
}
```

I just need the `hc/rc` field.

I can't access direclty using `res.data.hc` (prompting sound null safety issue).

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

Thakns for all's inputs.

The map returns OK.

Now in the `FutureBuilder`, I am trying to do something like this:

```
class _ReadCardState extends State<ReadCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        future: getReading(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var res = snapshot.data;
            var hc = res?['hc'] ?? 'n/a';
            print(hc);
            var rc = res?['rc'] ?? '/na';
            print(rc);
            final text = '截止，共评论书籍$hc本，读书笔记$rc篇';

            return Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.glasses,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      size: 50,
                    ),
                    title: Text('读书'),
                    subtitle: Text('截止，共评论书籍$hc本，读书笔记$rc篇'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

The two `print` statements correctly prints the numbers. The problem is when I want to insert these two values into a `Text` widget, it is a compile time error:

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/My Programs/rsywx/lib/CardBuilder/ReadCard.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": {
        "value": "const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
            "path": "/diagnostics/const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor.\nTry using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 38,
    "startColumn": 36,
    "endLineNumber": 38,
    "endColumn": 59
}
```

Any further help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277243/7972633 might help you out.

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69116765/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thanks. Your method shows null safety issue in current flutter.

Answer (score 0):

The casting is causing the error, use `as`. Btw, you don't really need a cast here. Plus, you can't access map items with something like `res.data.hc`, only if you convert the result into an object. Try this code:

```
const jsonString =
    '{ "statusCode": 200, "data": {  "hc": "148", "rc": "182"}}';
final jsonDecoded = jsonDecode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(jsonDecoded["data"]["hc"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to cast. It will work without casting. But if you need to access fields like this `res.data.hc` then you need to convert the decoded result to custom object [Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes).

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getReading() async {
  const uri = 'https://xxxxxxxxx';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri));

  if (response.statusCode == HTTP_OK) {
    var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var hc = res["data"]["hc"];
    return res;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Reading summary data.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad...

The issue raised from the `const` keyword on the `ListTile`. Taking this out, everything is perfectly fine.